# MySQL Query taking cartesian product

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on creating a small messaging platform and I have three tables:

```
`msg_conversations`
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

`msg_participants`
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| convo_id   | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| prof_id    | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| prof_type  | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_visible | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

`msg_messages`
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| participant_id | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| message        | text                | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| time_cre       | int(11)             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to return the newest message (by msg_messages.time_cre) along with the convo_id's for each conversation that a participant is in.

My logic is as follows: 1) get all conversation id's a user is participating in (defined by msg_participants.prof_type and msg_participants.prof_id). 2) Get every single participant based on each conversation id. 3) Return the last message (sorted by msg_messages.time_cre) in each conversation. The functionality should be similar to how Facebook returns a list of conversations along with a preview of the last message in each conversation.

Here's my code so far:

```
SELECT msg_participants.convo_id,
    msg_messages.id,
    msg_participants.prof_id,
    msg_participants.prof_type,
    SUBSTRING(msg_messages.message,1,50) as message,
    msg_messages.time_cre
FROM msg_participants,msg_messages
WHERE
    msg_participants.id IN 
        (SELECT participant_id FROM 
            (SELECT * FROM (SELECT msg_messages.participant_id,msg_participants.convo_id FROM msg_messages,msg_participants WHERE msg_messages.participant_id=msg_participants.id AND participant_id IN 
                (SELECT id FROM msg_participants WHERE convo_id IN (SELECT convo_id FROM msg_participants WHERE prof_id=PROFILE_ID_HERE AND prof_type=PROFILE_TYPE_HERE))
            ORDER BY time_cre DESC) AS tbl1
            GROUP BY tbl1.convo_id) AS tbl2)

    AND msg_messages.id IN 
        (SELECT id FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT msg_messages.id,msg_participants.convo_id FROM msg_messages,msg_participants WHERE msg_messages.participant_id=msg_participants.id AND participant_id IN 
                (SELECT id FROM msg_participants WHERE convo_id IN (SELECT convo_id FROM msg_participants WHERE prof_id=PROFILE_ID_HERE AND prof_type=PROFILE_TYPE_HERE)) 
            ORDER BY time_cre DESC) AS tbl3
            GROUP BY tbl3.convo_id) AS tbl4)
```

I know how ugly/hacky my code is, but I am at the point where I've rewritten it so many times that I just want something that works. This code is...close. But it returns a Cartesian product of msg_participants.id X msg_messages.id. It makes sense to me as to why it's returning the Cartesian product, but I'm not sure how to make this query do what I want it to do.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you don't understand how relational databases work.  There needs to be relations. This means joins in SQL.  But there does not seem to be the data in your model for the joins.  How do you know what conversation a message is from.  You only know who the said it... but people can have more than one conversation.  In any case your query should have JOIN statements not IN statements.

Comment: I am using joins, just not explicitly. They way I know what conversation a message is from is by msg_messages.participant_id -> msg_participants.id -> msg_participants.convo_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `not exists` to select the most recent row from `msg_messages` for a given `participant_id`

```
select mp.convo_id, mm.id, mp.prof_id, mp.prof_type, mm.message, mm.time_cre
from msg_participants mp
join msg_messages mm on mp.id = mm.participant_id
where mp.prof_id = PROF_ID_HERE
and mp.prof_type = PROF_TYPE_HERE 
and not exists (
    select 1 from msg_messages mm2
    where mm2.participant_id = mm.participant_id
    and mm2.time_cre > mm.time_cre
)
```